# Client/Server program error in initializing KeyManagerFactoryImpl

Tags: java, ssl, server, client

I am creating a client and a server that connect via java SSL sockets. Only the server is authenticated (one-way authentication). After the client connects to the server, the client will prompt the user for a single line of input and send it to the server.

Whenever I run the client I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl.engineGetKeyManagers(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(KeyManagerFactory.java:289)
    at SSLClient.createSSLContext(SSLClient.java:43)
    at SSLClient.main(SSLClient.java:50)
```

My Client code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class SSLClient {

    public static final int PORT_NO = 9020;
    static void doProtocol( Socket cSock ) throws IOException
    {
        OutputStream     out = cSock.getOutputStream();
        InputStream      in = cSock.getInputStream();

        out.write("World".getBytes());
        out.write('!');

        int ch = 0;
        while ((ch = in.read()) != '!')
        {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
        }

        System.out.println((char)ch);
    }
    static SSLContext createSSLContext() throws Exception
    {
        // set up a key manager for our local credentials
        KeyManagerFactory mgrFact = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
//      KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

//      clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("client.p12"), "Password");

//      mgrFact.init(clientStore, "password");

        // create a context and set up a socket factory
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sslContext.init(mgrFact.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        return sslContext;
}

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        SSLContext       sslContext = createSSLContext();
        SSLSocketFactory fact = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
//        SSLSocketFactory fact = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket        cSock = (SSLSocket)fact.createSocket("localhost", PORT_NO);

        doProtocol(cSock);
    }
}
```

My Server code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.Certificate;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.x509.KeyFactory;


public class SSLSocketServer {

    public static int SERVER_PORT = 9020;


    static boolean isEndEntity( SSLSession session ) throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException
    {
            Principal id = session.getPeerPrincipal();
            if (id instanceof X500Principal)
            {
                X500Principal x500 = (X500Principal)id;
                String Expireddate = x500.getName("Expireddate");
                String Name = x500.getName("Name");
                return (Name.equals("James") && Date.parse(Expireddate) > System.currentTimeMillis());
            }

            return false;
     }


    /**
     * Carry out the '!' protocol - server side.
     */
    static void doProtocol(
        Socket sSock)
        throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("session started.");

        InputStream in = sSock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = sSock.getOutputStream();
        // Send Key

        out.write("Hello ".getBytes());

        int ch = 0;
        while ((ch = in.read()) != '!')
        {
            out.write(ch);
        }

        out.write('!');

        sSock.close();
    }
    /**
     * Create an SSL context with identity and trust stores in place
     */
    SSLContext createSSLContext() 
        throws Exception
    {
        // set up a key manager for our local credentials
        KeyManagerFactory mgrFact = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore serverStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        serverStore.load(new FileInputStream("server.jks"), "password".toCharArray());

        mgrFact.init(serverStore, "password".toCharArray());

        // set up a trust manager so we can recognize the server
        TrustManagerFactory trustFact = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("trustStore.jks"), "trustpassword".toCharArray());

        trustFact.init(trustStore);

        // create a context and set up a socket factory
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sslContext.init(mgrFact.getKeyManagers(), trustFact.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return sslContext;
    }


    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        SSLServerSocketFactory fact = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket        sSock = (SSLServerSocket)fact.createServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

        SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket)sSock.accept();
        sSock.setNeedClientAuth(false); // current ignore

        doProtocol(sslSock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call one of the `KeyManagerFactories` init methods:

```
init(KeyStore ks, char[] password)
```

or

```
init(ManagerFactoryParameters spec)
```

prior to calling `KeyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()` otherwise it will throw the observed `IllegalStateException`.

Your code could for example look somthing like this:

```
...
final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
try (final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fullPathOfKeyStore())) {
    keyStore.load(is, JKS_PASSWORD);
}
final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, KEY_PASSWORD);
...
```

See [programcreek.com](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory) for full example.